# How to create the page in wordPress using RestAPI

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I'm Try to create the page in wordpress using RestAPI.
url : /wp-json/wp/v2/pages
Type:Post,
Request parms:

```
{"date":"2017-11-08 03:01:46","date_gmt":"2017-11-08 03:01:46","slug,status":"woo","password":"W47lFMylD9u3q&WUln","parent":"1","title":"new","content":"test","author":1,"excerpt":"1","featured_media":"1","comment_status":"open","ping_status":"open","menu_order":"1","meta":[],"template":"template-homepage.php"}
```

But it showing this error

```
{
"code": "rest_cannot_edit_others",
"message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.",
"data": {
    "status": 401
}
}
```

I'm using post man for checking API where to give my wordpress API key I given in basic, oauth1.0 and oauth 2.0 autentication but not working. Can any one help on this issue?

Comment: You've added the request twice and not the error.

Comment: Now changed @RoolPaap

Comment: check solution Link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430162/displaying-rest-api-data-in-angular-from-wordpress-woocommerce/47430518#47430518

Answer (score 1):

Try below Example,

```html
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Rest API Page
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Seventeen
 * @since 1.0
 * @version 1.0
 */

?>

<?php
 //echo "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts where post_type = 'post' ";
 $posts = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts where post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'" );

 $items = array();
 foreach ($posts as $post) {
  $item['title']  = get_the_title($post->ID);
  $item['url']   = get_permalink($post->ID);
  $item['desc']  = $post->excerpt;
  $item['image']  = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
  $item['thumb']  = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Thumbnail', true);
  $items[]     = $item;
  // $result[] = array('post_title'=>$post_title);
 }
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$items));

?>
```

Comment: I need to create the post or page in wordpress using API dynamically not to get the post value :)

Comment: @RaghulRajendran, currently I am also working on same. If I will get the solution the I will share with you... :)