# Displaying REST API data in Angular from WordPress/WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I am working on a word press/woocomerce website and I will use Angular for the theme. I have a REST API for it, and I was using Postman to test the API.

I have used `/wp-json/wc/v2/products?g_json` to display all products, but all I get from Postman is

```
{
    "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
    "message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

I saw there is some auth to do, but I don't know how to use it. If I add a key for API auth, how will I be able to get data with this API?
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/

I know how to get data from an API, but I have no idea what to do if I am required to send some keys so I can get data from API.

Thanks to anyone who helps me.

Answer (score 1):

Used JSON Basic Authentication plugin and used chrome postman addon

[image]

Plugin Link:-  https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth